# Latex Title Page (Minipage Formatting)

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

I've got some problems with my minipage adjustment. I want "Author" and "Supervisor" to be on the same line but for some reason I cannot fathom "Supervisor" is barely on the same line as `Test1 \textsc{Test1}`, in fact a bit below.

That's my setup:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\allowdisplaybreaks
```

and that's my code:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{flushleft} \large
  \emph{Students:}\\
    Test1 \textsc{Test1}\\
    Test2 \textsc{Test2}\\
    Test3 \textsc{Test3}\\
  \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage} 
~
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{flushright} \large
  \emph{Supervisor} \\
    Prof. Dr. Test \textsc{Test}\\
  \end{flushright}     
\end{minipage}\\[2 cm]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}` for both (untested).

Comment: You are also welcome to read about Title Creation in the [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation).

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/titlepageExamples/blob/master/walrus.tex